# What is the technical name for this flexible metal hose?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I wanted to buy this type of flexible metal hose connected to the spray gun of my kitchen sink tap. As I do not know its specific name, specifically the type of connection used at the two ends, my Google search ends up with irrelevant result. The hardware stores in my country don't seem to have it. The outer diameter of the thin end connecting to the tap is 13mm, the fat end connecting to the spray gun is typical type used in shower hose.

[image: flexible metal hose]

The tap in question looks like this.

[image: kitchen tap]

The tap I bought from China, taobao. I'm from Singapore.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We can't see enough of the connections from here to help you. Perhaps if you posted close-ups of the ends with a ruler, but probably the best way is to take the hose to your local hardware store and ask.

Comment: @Daniel, see my revised qn. I tried asking many stores already.

Comment: I'd contact the manufacturer. It's not impossible to find the ends, but as you're seeing, its not necessarily straight forward. I wish cell phones all used the EXACT same charing interface! (thats an example, and truth)

Comment: **"You won't find generic" is an understatement.** I replaced a kitchen faucet. Missing tube for sprayer that goes inside hole in corner of sink. Contacted manufacturer (Delta). Great service - they sent me an entire sprayer/hose+tube. But the hose wouldn't fit the attachment point on the faucet and the tube wouldn't fit the first hose - **two different types for the same model faucet**. I went back to Home Depot: I didn't have receipt but they found my order in the system. Went to the shelf. Opened a box and said take whatever parts you need! All for a missing 50-cent plastic tube.

Comment: I had the EXACT same issue @manassehkatz with a Kohler 3-way diverter valve (well, I guess its 4........), hot, cold, faucet, and sprayer, all fancy all plastic, and it was missing one locking clip, which was NOT the same as what was in the box on another one we opened. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a "sprayer hose". Each faucet manufacturer has its own proprietary design. You won't find generic parts. All it has to fit is the other parts they make. There's no motivation to use standard fittings. In fact, the design can change mid-stream during a model's production run.

Contact the manufacturer or an aftermarket vendor for exact replacement parts.